# How to use scipy.optimize.basinhopping and scipy.optimize.minimum?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I've already read the documentation for both but I'm still confused about how to use them (I'm taking an intro CS class for python so I'm not very familiar with programming). Can anyone provide some very basic examples of what the code might look like?

For example, how would I use basin hopping to find the minimum of an equation with two variables such as f(x,y) = x^2*y^2 + cos(x)*sin(y) with x and y in the range -5 < x,y < 5 ?

And for minimize, how might I find the minimum of something like f(x) = x^3 - cos(2*pi*x)?

Please keep the examples as simple as possible! (I really didn't understand the code in the documentation at all, I don't think we learned scipy as in depth as that)

Here are some examples of what I've tried so far:

Basinhopping:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

def f(xy): #(I don't know what to do for x and y here)  
    return x**2*y**2+np.cos(x)*np.sin(y)

guess = np.array(-5,5)
result = spo.basinhopping(f, guess)
print(result)
```

Minimize:

```
def g(x):
    return x**2 - np.cos(2*np.pi*x)

result2 = spo.minimize(g)  
print(result2)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us a minimal code example.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I've added some examples of what I've tried!

Comment: You can format code with the {} button or with CTRL-K. What is your question for minimize? The error message tells you everything, you need to know.